# Move swap and extend home partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Win8.1. For some reason (my mistake) I have my home partition (80GB) than swap (4GB) and then 200GB of unallocated space (in that order). I want to use this free space. Can I move swap partition on the end of unallocated space and extend home partition (with-out loss of data)? Or should I just make another partition where the unallocated space is. Does the position of partitions matter or no? (Someone said to me once that swap should be at the end.)

Comment: You can do it pretty easily, but you'll have to do it from a LiveCD/USB.

Comment: Yes I see. I was not sure about removing and recreating swap, but everything else is very nicely explained. I will mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the swap doesn't have any data stored on it, you can swapoff, remove the swap volume, extend your home-partition and recreate the swap at the end of the drive.

Comment: But will extending the home partition do any damage to existing data present there?